# undefined method 'created_events' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm coding a project from "The Odin Project" about Rails Associations. I thought I had get the topic pretty well, but I hit a block.

I'm getting a **NoMethodError in EventsController#new** // **Undefined method 'created_events' for nil:NilClass**

Here's my User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  has_many :created_events, :foreign_key => :creator_id, :class_name => 'Event', :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Event Model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

EventsController:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    @created_event = @user.created_events.build
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    @created_event = @user.created_events.build(event_params)

    if @created_event.save
      flash[:notice] = "Event was successfully created!"
      redirect_to @created_event
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, :location, :date, :description)
    end
end
```

And my 'new' view, which I'm not sure it's 100% correct given I've messed with it a bit.

```
<h1>New Event</h1>
<%= form_for @created_event do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :location %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :date %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

For simplicity, I've included the form on the page, although in my project I've it stashed in a partial.

**I've tested 'created_events' in the rails console, and it worked but on the site, it gives me the error.**

If someone can tell me how to fix this, and what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It says the problem is in `EventsController#new` and the error means `@user` is `nil`, so `User.find_by_email(params[:email])` doesn't return a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such user exists in your database with the email which is returned by `params[:email]`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I changed it to find the user by the current_user.id instead of email.

Answer (score 0):

`User.find_by_email(params[:email])` does not find a user with the email parameter you pass to it so there's your problem.